# Keycloak urls setup

Tags: keycloak

I want to run Keycloak and to play with it. So I run a container in Docker with `quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:20.0.1` image.

```yaml
version: '3.8'

networks:
  default-dev-network:
    external: true

services:
  keycloak:
    container_name: keycloak
    image: quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:20.0.1
    environment:
      KC_DB: postgres
      KC_DB_URL: jdbc:postgresql://postgresdb:5432/keycloak
      KC_DB_USERNAME: postgres
      KC_DB_PASSWORD: pass
      KC_DB_SCHEMA: public

      KC_HOSTNAME: localhost
      KC_HTTPS_PORT: 8443
      KC_HTTPS_PROTOCOLS: TLSv1.3,TLSv1.2
      KC_HTTP_ENABLED: "true"
      KC_HTTP_PORT: 8080
      KC_METRICS_ENABLED: "true"

      KEYCLOAK_ADMIN: admin
      KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PASSWORD: password

    ports:
      - 18080:8080
      - 8443:8443

    command: start-dev

    networks:
      - default-dev-network
```

Then I created a realm `test-realm`, a client `test-client`. So I want to request a bearer token for it. I run

```bash
curl \
    -d 'client_id=test-client' \
    -d 'client_secret=xajewuZlBHL75rpiPttHday8t34aOnYa' \
    -d 'grant_type=client_credentials' \
    'http://localhost:18080/auth/realms/test-realm/protocol/openid-connect/token'
```

and I get

```
{"error":"RESTEASY003210: Could not find resource for full path: http://localhost:18080/auth/realms/test-realm/protocol/openid-connect/token"}
```

I'm reading a documentation on https://www.keycloak.org but there're so many details there that I'm afraid it will take weeks to figure everything out. Maybe there's a shorter guide?

Comment: Please post how you are running the Docker container.

Comment: Updated with docker-compose file

Comment: In the new Keycloak versions there is no `/auth` path. You can either remove it from your curl or set the property `KC_HTTP_RELATIVE_PATH=/auth`

Comment: Please move it to a separate response so I can mark it as and answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

New versions of Keycloak (after the rewrite in Quarkus) removed the `/auth` context path.
You can either remove it from the url or set the property `KC_HTTP_RELATIVE_PATH=/auth`.